# understanding stdout, stderr and stdin

Tags: linux, file, unix, operating-system

```
root@C6903:/ # ls -l /proc/327/fd/
lrwx------ root     root              1970-02-11 01:40 0 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ root     root              1970-02-11 01:40 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ root     root              1970-02-11 01:40 2 -> /dev/null
```

As i can see, all(0, 1, 2) are pointing to /dev/null. Why? How do they differ internally?

In my case(Coredump environment), the fd's list is something like this.

```
root@C6903:/ # ls -l /proc/5987/fd/                            
lr-x------ root     root              1970-02-11 01:34 0 -> pipe:[31608]
```

So stdout and stderr files are not present. In this scenario, if i give a `printf()`, i am facing undefined behaviour(other opened files are over-written). To solve this,
I am doing something like below:

```
int check_fd(int fd)
{
    return (fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) != -1);
}
```

...

```
    if (!check_fd(STDOUT_FILENO))
        fopen("/dev/null", "w");

    if (!check_fd(STDERR_FILENO))
        fopen("/dev/null", "w");
```

This is working well. But am afraid if i am doing something wrong. How can i differentiate between stdout and stderr if i have to open them?

Comment: `man freopen`.  Simply calling fopen may open a file with 1 or 2 as the underlying file descriptor, but that doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`stdout`, `stdin`, and `stderr` point to different pipes or sockets according to the way the program was launched. In the first case, they all have been redirected to `/dev/null` so there is no output whatsoever on the standard output, and as for the input, using `/dev/null` is a convenient way to pass an empty file.

If you need to differentiate between them, you need to redirect them to different files. In this case, it's not a very good idea to use `/dev/null` for both. You can for example open two different files: `program.stdout` and `program.stderr` and then write in each separately

Comment: 'No output whatsoever' is not correct.  From the program's perspective, it is happily writing data, and there is IO from program memory to kernel memory.  That data is discarded by the kernel, but since it gets copied from user space to kernel space, it is not accurate to say that there is 'no output'.

Comment: I meant no output on standard output

Comment: But there is output on standard out!  The fact that that data is discarded does not mean it never got output from the process.

Comment: Yes, I know, I meant the data is discarded instead of being displayed on standart output

Comment: You seem to believe that "stdout" is a display device, and that is the misunderstanding I am trying to correct.  Data is written to stdout.  In this case (as in many, probably most), stdout is not a tty.

Answer (score 0):

If stdout and stderr have been closed and you want to reopen them, try:

```
freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stdout );
```